# Java Deserialization and ArrayList weird Exception

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, boolean, classcastexception

Im having a problem when I try to deserialize an ArrayList, the .readObject() method is returning a boolean instead of an object, and I have no clue why this is happening. Thank you and sorry for the bad english.

**Class to be serialized**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Pessoa implements Serializable {

public String nome;
public String sobrenome;
public int idade;

public Pessoa(String n, String sn, int i){
    this.nome = n;
    this.sobrenome = sn;
    this.idade = i;
}
}
```

**Serialization and Deserialization**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TESTES {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("Tony", "Stark", 35);
    ArrayList<Pessoa> listaPessoas = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("obj.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        oos.writeObject(listaPessoas.add(p1));
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TESTES.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TESTES.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("obj.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        //===== HERES THE PROBLEM =========================
        listaPessoas = (ArrayList<Pessoa>) ois.readObject();
        //===== HERES THE PROBLEM =========================

        ois.close();

        System.out.println(listaPessoas.get(0).nome);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TESTES.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TESTES.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

**The Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be          cast to java.util.ArrayList
at testes.TESTES.main(TESTES.java:41)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: You use Java 7; therefore, use `Files.newInputStream()` instead of `new FileInputStream()`

Comment: Also you have another problem: you do not declare a `serialVersionUID` in your class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the serialization:

```
oos.writeObject(listaPessoas.add(p1));
```

this writes the return value of `List.add()` which is a boolean (true if the collection is changed by the operation) which is then boxed in a `Boolean`.

When you then deserialize:

```
 listaPessoas = (ArrayList<Pessoa>) ois.readObject();
```

a Boolean is found in the stream, but you try to cast it to List, generating the class cast exception.

Just keep the serialization of the list in a single statements like:

```
 listaPessoas.add(value);
 [...] // other operation on the list
 oos.writeObject(listaPessoas);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this line:

```
oos.writeObject(listaPessoas.add(p1));
```

The Java Collections API is not fluent. The `add` method doesn't return the List, but instead a `boolean` indicating whether the operation was successful. So you should split above line into two like this:

```
listaPessoas.add(p1);
oos.writeObject(listaPessoas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the `ArrayList` to the `ObjectOutputStream` and not the return value of the `add` method.

```
 listaPessoas.add(p1)
 oos.writeObject(listaPessoas);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are serializing the boolean variable 
oos.writeObject(listaPessoas.add(p1));  -- add()return value is boolean.

You should do like this.
listaPessoas.add(p1);
oos.writeObject(arraylistobject);